# C# How to user timers on labels?

Tags: c#, timer, label

I have a label pop up letting the user when they click the copy button that it's been copied using a label in the bottom right on the app. But I want the text to go away after 2 or so seconds. Then come back if they click copy again, this is my copy buttons code:

```
        private void copyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelCopied.Text = "Copied to Clipboard!";
        Clipboard.SetText(btcTxtBox.Text);
        SystemSounds.Hand.Play();

    }
```

I do know labelCopied.Text.Remove(0); would clear the label but I cannot figure out how to implement it using a timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Timer` for this:

```
private void copyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelCopied.Text = "Copied to Clipboard!";
    Clipboard.SetText(btcTxtBox.Text);
    SystemSounds.Hand.Play();

    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Interval = 2000; //2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
    t.Tick += (a,b) =>
    {
         labelCopied.Text = string.Empty;
         t.Stop();
    };

    t.Start();
}
```

**EDIT**

`Task.Delay` uses a `Timer` internally. So if you don't mind a minimal performance overhead, `Task.Delay` is good to go. Additionally `Task.Delay` is more portable since `Timer` is `WinForms` specific (In `WPF` you would use `DispatcherTimer`)

```
private async void copyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelCopied.Text = "Copied to Clipboard!";
    Clipboard.SetText(btcTxtBox.Text);
    SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    labelCopied.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, which would you recommend it is WinForms naturally. Timer or the Task.Delay?

Comment: `Task.Delay` uses a `Timer` internally. So if you don't mind a minimal performance overhead, `Task.Delay` is good to go. Additionally `Task.Delay` is more portable since `Timer` is `WinForms` specific (In `WPF` you would use `DispatcherTimer`)

Comment: Thank you,much better than thread sleep as it pauses the application.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms, use [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) with [Task.Delay()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
private async void copyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelCopied.Text = "Copied to Clipboard!";
    Clipboard.SetText(btcTxtBox.Text);
    SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    labelCopied.Text = "";
}
```